# the relationship between hypothesis test and confidence interval?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

How to understand the relationship between hypothesis test and confidence interval?

Comment: @Erik: Perhaps it's about construction of confidence intervals by test inversion.

Comment: I just saw test inversion's addressed in DavidR's answer to that question, in any case. @user3269: perhaps you could have a look & see if you still have any doubts.